# The sentence in bold seems unclear to me

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> In these books written to edify and instruct American boys, success was the goal to strive for, and success was to be measured by rising above the station one was born into, or, to put it more baldly, by doing better than one's father. If your father was a butcher, you should own the meat market; if he sold shoes, you should manufacture them. The trouble was that this process of outdoing one's forebear, generation after generation, was simply imposible. Only in a society of consistently rising expectations, like that of nineteenth-century America, could it have taken hold as  an ideal to be sought, **and only in a  society determinded to cling to outmoded values could it have continued to exert its power in the following century.**

I don' t understand the meaning of this sentence clearly and I don't know why this sentense is begun with "only".

Dose it mean that in these society this kind of way of thinking gradually effects and in a society of consistently rising expectation it show its effect soon?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The cited text represents the second of two syntactically identical sentences joined into a single "compound sentence" with the conjunction ***and***...

> 1: *Only in a society of consistently rising expectations, like that of nineteenth-century America, could it have taken hold as an ideal to be sought.*
>    2: *Only in a society determined to cling to outmoded values could it have continued to exert its power in the following century.*

...to which I'll add a third example, with the same basic syntax, but less words...

> 3: ***Only in Britain could this have happened***

It should now be easier to see that my simplified example is just a stylistic rearrangement of the normal word order...

> 4: ***This could only have happened in Britain***.

---

It's important to note that although it's possible to remove the word ***only*** from example #4, this *can't* be done with the stylistically inverted phrasing of example #3. That's to say,...

> 5: ***This could have happened in Britain***

...is a syntactically valid sentence (meaning ***It is possible*** [that] this happened in Britain), but...

> 6:  ??***In Britain could this have happened***

...is not idiomatically valid in any context.

It may also help to note that the adverbial element ***in Britain*** is in principle "optional" in the shortest valid *statement* above (example #5)...

> 7: ***This could have happened***

...in which context I should point out that **??** before example #6 indicates *unacceptable to almost all native speakers* (it's got nothing to do with asking questions). But with adverbial ***in Britain*** either removed completely, or placed at the *end* of the text, we're left with a perfectly normal question (with the standard "subject/verb inversion" used to form questions in English)...

> 8: ***Could this have happened?***
>    9: ***Could this have happened in Britain?***

---

TL;DR: The word ***only*** is syntactically necessary, since the example context is a *statement* (that the process being discussed couldn't have happened anywhere *except* in a society like American). If it's omitted, the remaining text could only be understood as a *question* (because of the subject/verb inversion ***could it have...*** rather than ***it could have...***). But semantically, a question would make no sense in this context.

---

FINALLY - it occurs to me that many people might struggle to understand what ***it*** refers to in the cited text ("it" being whatever "took hold as an ideal", and "continued to exert its power"). So just to spell it out,...

> **it** = *this process of outdoing one's forebear*
>    (i.e. - that the child should do better in life than the parent.)

Comment: Lots of thanks. But I thought the society of consistently rising expectation is differet from the society  determinded to cling to outmoded values but as I understood  from your answer both are discribing one society, the society of America in  nineteenth century. and I have another understanding : Dose some people in that century in America rose their expectations and some were clung to outmoded values?

Comment: No - nothing in your example text refers *in any way* to the possibility that ***some*** people in C19 America might have done or thought something different to ***other*** people in C19 America.

Comment: But do you say that these two societies "society of consistently rising expectation" and "society determined to cling in outmoded values" are the same. I mean their thoughts are the same.

Comment: what is the meaning of "it have continued to exert its power"?

Comment: Are you being misled because you assume *a society of consistently rising expectation* is a ***good*** thing, and *a society determined to cling in outmoded values* is a ***bad*** thing? And that any *actual, real-world* society must be either good or bad, so it can't be both of those things at once? Consider the syntactically identical (but simpler) *Only a rich country like the US could develop nanotech, and only a warmongering country could weaponise nanotech.* Does my sentence ***explicitly*** claim that the US is a warmongering country? Not really, but you might say it's ***implied***.

Comment: If we say something (such as the "social aspiration" under discussion) had the power to change how society evolved long ago, what's the problem with saying that it has *continued to exert its power* up until the present time?